# Android keep CountDownTimer running when app is in the background

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

In my app, I implement `CountDownTimer` in my listview as following:

`OrdersCountDownTimer.java`

```
public class OrdersCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    private OrdersAdapter adapter;

    public OrdersCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, OrdersAdapter adapter) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        adapter.decTime();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.start();
    }
}
```

`OrdersActivity.java`

`timer = new OrdersCountDownTimer(ONE_SECOND, ONE_SECOND, adapter);`

So, I'm decrementing the value in my `Order` object upon every tick my timer finishes.

The problem is that this is running in my main thread, which means when my app goes to the background or the screen is locked, the `timer` is paused as well.

I would like to keep the `timer` running at all times. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can use service to make things run in background even after you close the app  Tutorial1: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm       Tutorial2:                                                  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @Saravlnfern Ah then placing that service in a separate process will be the way to go?

Comment: yes, you can start the service as a separate process

Comment: @Saravlnfern Hmm would creating a separate thread to run the timer be effortless? I'm asking cuz I don't seem to fully understand the thread and process. The action of putting my main thread in the background means a "pause on the process" hence all threads that live in this process pauses?

Comment: By default, all components of the same application run in the same process.If you kill your app the process is terminated by android, you should start a service as a separate process  if you want to run some background work even if you kill your app. you can refer android developer guide here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html